# Android : JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject

Tags: android, arrays, json, object

I have a project in Android, and I have this JSON right here that I need to parse so I can use the data: (I've tried to validate my JSON at JSONLint.com, and it's all good)

```
{
    "traces": [
        "{\"lat\": \"42.842097\", \"lng\": \"-31.258422\", \"idTrace\": \"444e8079\"}",
        "{\"lat\": \"56.842097\", \"lng\": \"-73.258422\", \"idTrace\": \"088b591a\"}"
    ]
}
```

The problem is that I always get an error when I try to get the 2 JSONObjects inside the JSONArray.

Here's a snippet of my code :

```
     (...)

     StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();

     for (String line = null; (line = reader.readLine()) != null;) 
     {
          builder.append(line).append("\n");
     }


    JSONObject result = new JSONObject(builder.toString());
    JSONArray list = result.getJSONArray("traces");


    try{
        for (int i = 0; i < list.length(); i++)
            {     //this is where I get the error "JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject"
              JSONObject jsonObject = list.optJSONObject(i); 


              //String id = jsonObject.getString("idTrace");
              //String lat = jsonObject.getString("lat");
              //String lng = jsonObject.getString("lng");

                 (...)
             }
      (...)
```

I've searched lot to find what the problem is, but people seem to be doing the exact same thing as I do... I can't find the reason why it's not working!

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Try `list.optJSONObject(i);` instead of `liste.optJSONObject(i);`

Comment: There is a typo in your loop. Was that just from typing in the question or in your actual code?

Comment: I mistyped it, I'm sorry, the problem is still there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this JSON coming back from an API that you control? I think what's breaking things are the quotes around the items in the JSONArray - the JSON should look like this:

```
{"traces": [
    {"lat": "42.842097", "lng": "-31.258422", "idTrace": "444e8079"},
    {"lat": "56.842097", "lng": "-73.258422", "idTrace": "088b591a"} 
]}
```

Note that there are no quotes around each of the JSONObjects. What you have now is more like an array of strings...

Comment: well actually, I'm producing this JSON from a web service I created in python. I can show you how I proceeded:

Comment: for animal in animals.all(): 
   data = {'idTrace' : str(animal.uuid), 'lat': str(animal.latitudeOrigine), 'lng': str(animal.longitudeOrigine)}
         struct_finale['traces'].append(json.dumps(data))
pass
return HttpResponse(json.dumps({'traces' : struct_finale['traces']}), content_type="application/json")

Comment: I'll see if it is possible to remove all the quotes in python

Comment: well, you're going to need quotes around your keys and values...just not around each element of the array

Comment: yeah I know what you mean, I never noticed actually that it came out like that :  "{\"lat\": ... I believe this might be the problem! thanks!

Comment: yep! I made myself a custom encoder for the json, it's working now, thanks again for pointing this out!

Answer (score 0):

It is your typo error,

```
liste.optJSONObject(i); this should be list.optJSONObject(i);
```

Comment: no I'm sorry I mistyped it, this is not the problem, but thanks! I just edited it

Comment: this doesn't solve the problem, the difference between getJSONObject and optJSONObject is that it returns null instead of "crashing" and stopping the app

Comment: @user2179985 Are you getting any exception or eclipse show you warning..?

Comment: It is hard to find the problem, with the above code, because everything seem to be good. So post all your code so we can identify is there any error in it..

Comment: everytime the app hits the line " JSONObject jsonObject = list.optJSONObject(i);", it goes into the exception

Comment: @user2179985 Please post your logcat cat trace, that is a pricious information for us, the reason why I have asked you to post your code, is to check whether is there any other variable with the name list. Ok post your logcat trace.

Comment: well, I can't seem to produce anything in the logcat except this : JSONArray[0] is not a JSONObject... I can assure you there's no other variable with the name "list"

Comment: this is what "list" contains : [
        "{\"lat\": \"42.842097\", \"lng\": \"-31.258422\", \"idTrace\": \"444e8079\"}",
        "{\"lat\": \"56.842097\", \"lng\": \"-73.258422\", \"idTrace\": \"088b591a\"}"
    ]

Comment: I believe the problem comes from the JSON I'm producing, thanks for the help